# Placing generated JavaScript URL into `<a href="{{Text here}}">`

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have an external JavaScript that generates 4 numbers and puts them between 2 parts of text, like this

```js
document.getElementById("gen3").textContent = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Lego+set:+" + first + fnum + snum + tnum + "&num=30&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj08YDU_MjSAhXLLMAKHSp4CxQQ_AUICCgB&biw=1366&bih=669";
```

```html
<p>
<input id="gen-btn" type="button" value="Generate" onclick="postmessage();" />
</p>

<div id="gen3"></div>
```

It generates properly and selecting it and opening it in a new tab works perfectly, but I'd like to make it easier by placing it directly into an href.

Comment: you can't. not with JS.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, can you explain more thoroughly?

Comment: he wants to have `<a href="...{link here} ...">text</a>`, output by javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `div` into an `a` (anchor tag) in your HTML and use its `href` property in JavaScript to set the URL destination used when you click it. You can also choose to set its `textContent` to the same value, which makes it clearer to people using the tool where exactly they are going when they click the link.

```
gen3.href = gen3.textContent = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Lego+set:+" + first + fnum + snum + tnum + "&num=30&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj08YDU_MjSAhXLLMAKHSp4CxQQ_AUICCgB&biw=1366&bih=669"
```

---

### Demo Snippet

```js
var gen3 = document.getElementById("gen3")

function postmessage() {
  // Pretending these are "random" values, and assuming you have the code for them already
  var first = 1,
    fnum = 2,
    snum = 3,
    tnum = 4

  // Later...
  gen3.href = gen3.textContent = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Lego+set:+" + first + fnum + snum + tnum + "&num=30&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj08YDU_MjSAhXLLMAKHSp4CxQQ_AUICCgB&biw=1366&bih=669"
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input id="gen-btn" type="button" value="Generate" onclick="postmessage();" />
</p>
<p>
  <a id="gen3"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Glad to help! If you wouldn't mind accepting this answer if the problem is solved, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `anchor` tag inside the `div`

Then you can do like this

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("linkText").setAttribute('href','www.google.com')
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="gen3">
 <a href="" id="linkText">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/62p9v4c3/1/)